# can't get generics to work - doesn't accept variable

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to return an object based on the input variable in my generic method, but I get

> The type `T` cannot be used as type parameter `T` in the generic type
>   or method `IApiDbRepository<T>` Theres is no implicit reference
>   conversion from `T` to `IApiBase`

**Code**:

```
public interface IApiDbUnitOfWork
{
    IApiDbRepository<T> GetRepo<T>() where T : class, IApiBase;
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
    IApiDbContextHelper Helper { get; }
}

public class ApiDbUnitOfWork : IApiDbUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IApiDbContextHelper _helper;
    private IApiDbContextHelper dbHelper;

    public ApiDbUnitOfWork(IApiDbContextHelper helper)
    {
        _helper = helper;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns specified repo
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of repo</typeparam>
    /// <returns>A repo based on specified type</returns>
    public IApiDbRepository<T> GetRepo<T>() where T : class, IApiBase
    {
        return new ApiDbRepository<T>(_helper);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Async save changes to database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Number of entries written to the database</returns>
    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return await _helper.DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public IApiDbContextHelper Helper => _helper;
}
```

**ApiBase**:

```
public interface IApiBase
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    Guid UId { get; set; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    bool Active { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ApiBase : IApiBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
}
```

every object in the solutions inherits from `IApiBase`

Comment: What every happened to KISS?

Comment: Before even attempting to find the problem at hand: you should know that the repository pattern should be avoided unless you have very specific reasons for using it. This looks like an EF wrapper and that's a waste of your time

Comment: but do you know what I need to do to get working?

Comment: How is `ApiDbRepository` defined?

Comment: What does ApiDbRepository look like and what does the call to GetRepo<T> look like?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  My guess is that you have a `T` that doesn't implement `IApiBase`

Comment: `but I get` Which line of code causes that error?

Comment: Your example [compiles fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hX4gZZ). Is something missing?